# How to declare my column as a vector?

Tags: c++, vector

My code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>

int main(){
    std::ifstream ifs("MFSO7.dat");
    std::string line;

    while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // read one line from ifs
    {
        std::istringstream iss(line); // access line as a stream
        float column1;
        float column2;
        float column3;

        iss >> column1;
        std::cout << column1 << std::endl;
    }

   std::vector<float> v1 = column1;
   std::vector<float> v2;
   transform(v1.begin(), v1.end(), back_inserter(v2),[](float n){return std::pow(n,2);});
   copy(v2.begin(), v2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>( std::cout, " "));

}
```

I have read three columns from my txt file,then I need just the first one for further calculations.I want to use pow to square all the elements.But I got

```
k.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
k.cpp:24:28: error: ‘column1’ was not declared in this scope
    std::vector<float> v1 = column1;
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Add the elements to the vector one by one.

Comment: `column1`, `column2` and `column3` should be declared out of the while loop to be accessed outside the loop

Comment: @Lucacox Declared as a vector?

Comment: Don't listen to him. Even if you declare it outside, the variables will only contain the last value.

Comment: yes, outside you declare the vector and inside the loop you fill it with the values from the file

Comment: @Karoly my comment was purely sintactical: to access a variable you have to declare it in an accessible scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Declare three vectors that represent the columns before the `while` loop.
2. Fill up the contents of the vectors in the `while` loop.

```
std::vector<float> column1;
std::vector<float> column2;
std::vector<float> column3;

while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // read one line from ifs
{
    std::istringstream iss(line); // access line as a stream
    float item1;
    float item2;
    float item3;

    // Read the items from the line
    iss >> item1 >> item2 >> item3;

    // Add them to the columns.
    column1.push_back(item1);
    column2.push_back(item2);
    column3.push_back(item3);

    std::cout << item1 << " " << item2 << " " << item3 << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add the elements to the vector inside the loop:

```
std::vector<float> v1;
while(std::getline(ifs, line)) // read one line from ifs
{
    std::istringstream iss(line); // access line as a stream
    float column1;

    iss >> column1;
    v1.push_back(column1);
    std::cout << column1 << std::endl;
}

// now v1 contains the first column of numbers from your file
// go ahead and transform it into v2
```